# Graphene - How to add the extensions map to a query resolver

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

According to the GraphQL spec, extensions should be supported in the `response` map.  Reference https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sel-EAPHJCAACCoGu9J

> The response map may also contain an entry with key extensions. This entry, if set, must have a map as its value. This entry is reserved for implementors to extend the protocol however they see fit, and hence there are no additional restrictions on its contents.

How does one set that map in a graphene resolver method?  The documentation doesn't show that.